# Need to duplicate code

Tags: javascript, html

So guys I have a code that outputs text boxes and the information will be saved.

```
<tbody id="1111111">
    <tr>
    <td class="ObjektiivneLeid">The function</td>
    <td class="Hinnang">
    <input class="Hinnang_Valimata" type="radio" name="1111111_Hinnang" value="Valimata" id="1111111_Hinnang_Valimata" />Valimata
    <input class="Hinnang_norm" type="radio" name="1111111_Hinnang" id="364644000_Hinnang_NORM" value="NORM" />NORM
    <input class="Hinnang_pat checkbox_idParent" type="radio" name="1111111_Hinnang" id="1111111_Hinnang_Patoloogia" value="Patoloogia"/>Leid</td>
    <td class="Patoloogia">kuupäev
    <input id="1111111_otherInfo_kuupaev" name="1111111_otherInfo_kuupaev" type="text" value="" class="Patoloogia_text" onFocus="gnlGotFocus(getCurrentDate(),this);"
             onKeyDown="javascript:gnlKeyDown('00.00.0000',this,event);" maxlength='10'
             onblur="javascript:gnlDateValid(this,event,false);"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="title_sub Patoloogia">sight</td>
<td class="Patoloogia"><input id="1111111_otherInfo_sight" name="1111111_otherInfo_sight" type="text" value="" class="Patoloogia_text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="title_sub Patoloogia">hearing</td>
<td class="Patoloogia"><input id="364644000_otherInfo_hearing" name="364644000_otherInfo_hearing" type="text" value="" class="Patoloogia_text"></td>

<td class="title_sub Patoloogia">speech</td>
<td class="Patoloogia"><input id="1111111_otherInfo_speech" name="1111111_otherInfo_speech" type="text" value="" class="Patoloogia_text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="title_sub Patoloogia">mobility</td>
<td class="Patoloogia"><input id="1111111_otherInfo_mobility" name="1111111_otherInfo_mobility" type="text" value="" class="Patoloogia_text"></td>

<td class="title_sub Patoloogia">movement</td>
<td class="Patoloogia"><input id="1111111_otherInfo_movement" name="1111111_otherInfo_movement" type="text" value="" class="Patoloogia_text"></td>
</tr>`
```

So this is the code that gives me boxes to fill in and I need to make a adding system to that code, so when I press i.e. '+' it will duplicate the code and I have new fields to fill and save. Also I need and 'x' button to erase the new field if the need comes. Any suggestions how would I go by doing it (I hope my explanation wasn't to confusing)
I need something like `<tr><td colspan="4"><img src="./images/addButton.gif" alt="Add" border="0" onclick="" class="button" /></td></tr>` but I dont know what to pud in the onClick....I know it seems stupid but I really could use some help

Comment: off topic, but in general it is a bad idea to have IDs that are numeric. eg `id="1111111"`. You may have some browser compatibility issues if you use IDs like that.

Comment: I actually don't have that value, changed it to  id="1111111" I have tittles also in another language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you would be needing JQuery. Looking for something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dupe = $('#parent_0').clone();
    var id = 1;

    $(document).on('click', '#plus', function() {
        id++;
        var newForm = $(dupe).clone().attr('id', 'parent_'+id);

        $('body').append(newForm);
    });

   $(document).on('click', '#delete', function() {
       id--;
       $('[id^="parent_"]:last').remove();
   });
});
```

I have made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GMpZs/19/) based on your code for you to have a look at.

For demonstration purposes a div is used. There should be a **form** tag around your code since it actually is a form, but it seems JSFiddle doesn't like the use of forms in it's application. This **div** element will be cloned with **.clone()** and is given a unique attribute with **.attr()** when the button **#plus** is clicked.

**#delete** deletes the last clone element in the document whose id starts with *parent_*.

When you're posting stuff, make sure you paste the whole thing in the question.

Comment: Here's the right [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AK9CC/20/). I've accidentaly tried sending you the wrong fiddle. Too bad your question got downvoted. If the policing users of Stack Exchange would actualy help instead of downvoting a simple question, beginning programmers like you and I would be alot more motivated.

Comment: So I added all of my HTML code to JSFiddle and it doesn't work like I need it to work (I commented out the part that I need to be duplicated) So if you have any ideas how to fix the current problem, then it would be really nice http://jsfiddle.net/AK9CC/20/ is the link with the code.

Comment: Can't see in the fiddle what you had commented out. Which part would you like to have duplicated?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AK9CC/21/ sorry, that should be the right link, with the commented part at the end

Comment: or add jsfiddle.net/AK9CC/22 instead of jsfiddle.net/AK9CC/21, theres a different version off the same code that needs to be duplicated

Comment: You've commented out multiple parts of the HTML. You'd like to be able to dupe all of these?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AK9CC/22/ only whats under 'class="ObjektiivneLeid">Funktsioonide hindamine</td>'

Comment: Try using divs and labels instead of the whole table structure you've built. It seems to work then. I'll try help you later on to see if can still be done, but I think you'll have to rebuild a large part of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use appendChild(n) and removeChild(n) on the parent object containing the text boxes.